# Tensorflow tensor operation of different size along the last dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensor

I have a `tensor1` with shape `[1 128, 128 , 100]`, and I have another `tensor2` with shape `[1,128,128,1]`.
If I try to subtract `tensor1 - tensor2`, on the last dimension, will the `tensor2` automatically broadcast to `[1,128,128,100]` and operate the subtraction? Or it will only be subtracted the first layer of `tensor1`??

Thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will be broadcasted. The broadasting [rules](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) in tensorflow are the same as for numpy:

> When operating on two arrays, NumPy compares their shapes element-wise. It starts with the trailing dimensions, and works its way forward. Two dimensions are compatible when
>
> 1. they are equal, or
> 2. one of them is 1

For example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

v1 = tf.Variable(2*tf.ones([1, 2, 2, 3]))
v2 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([1, 2, 2, 1]))
diff = v1 - v2 

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(diff.eval()) # <-- `diff` contains only 'ones' because of broadcasting
# [[[[1. 1. 1.]
#    [1. 1. 1.]]
# 
#   [[1. 1. 1.]
#    [1. 1. 1.]]]]

print(diff.get_shape().as_list()) # [1, 2, 2, 3] <-- same shape as `v1`
```

In your case the trailing dimension of the second tensor is 1 and from rules it will be broadcastable. The rest of the dimensions are equal.